# Ibn Ezra List of Secrets

Tags: tanach, commentaries, avraham-ibn-ezra

Often times, Ibn Ezra will say something to the effect of "There is a secret here", and provide perhaps a few terse phrases by way of explanation.

For example, there is his famous Sod Hashneim Asar in the [beginning of Devarim](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.1.2?lang=he&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=he), and another example is in [Vayikra 16:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.16.8?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=he).

Can anyone provide a list of all (or as many as you know) times he does this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a simple filtered search on Sefaria does the trick:

Besides for the two you mentioned:

**Beresheet:**

[Beresheet 1:16](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Genesis.1.16.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Beresheet 2:8](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Genesis.2.8.2?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Beresheet 3:24](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Genesis.3.24.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Beresheet 7:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Genesis.7.4.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Beresheet 9:20](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Genesis.9.20.2?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Beresheet 12:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Genesis.12.6.4?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Beresheet 17:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Genesis.17.1.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Beresheet 24:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Genesis.24.3.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Beresheet 25:34](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Genesis.25.34.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Beresheet 28:16](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Genesis.28.16.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

**Shemot:**

[Shemot 6:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Exodus.6.3.6?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Shemot 23:21](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Exodus.33.21.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Shemot 25:40](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Exodus.25.40.3?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

[Shemot 29:25](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Exodus.29.25.2?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

**Vaykira:**

[Vayikra 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Leviticus.1.1.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Vayikra 17:13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Leviticus.17.13.2?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Vayikra 18:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Leviticus.18.6.5?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Vayikra 19:19](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Leviticus.19.19.2?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Vayikra 23:11](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Leviticus.23.11.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Vayikra 23:24](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Leviticus.23.24.2?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Vayikra 23:40](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Leviticus.23.40.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Vayikra 27:34](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Leviticus.27.34.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

**Bamidbar:**

[Bamidbar 6:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Numbers.6.2.3?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

[Bamidbar 7:72](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Numbers.7.72.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

[Bamidbar 19:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Numbers.19.6.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Bamidbar 22:28](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Numbers.22.28.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Bamidbar 23:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Numbers.23.1.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Bamidbar 23:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Numbers.23.3.3?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Bamidbar 28:15](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Numbers.28.15.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

**Devarim:**

[Devarim 4:35](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Deuteronomy.4.35.2?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Devarim 11:22](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Deuteronomy.11.22.4?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Devarim 32:8](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Deuteronomy.32.8.3?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Devarim 32:35](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Deuteronomy.32.35.3?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

**Yonah:**

[Yonah 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Jonah.1.1.1?vhe=Ibn_Ezra_on_Jonah_--_Daat&lang=bi)

**Tehillim:**

[Tehillim 119:90](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Psalms.119.90.1?vhe=Ibn_Ezra_on_Psalms_--_Daat&lang=bi)

**Iyov:**

[Iyov 1:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Job.1.6.1?vhe=Ibn_Ezra_on_Job_--_Daat&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

[Iyov 23:13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Job.23.13.1?vhe=Ibn_Ezra_on_Job_--_Daat&lang=bi)

[Iyov 28:26](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Job.38.36.2?vhe=Ibn_Ezra_on_Job_--_Daat&lang=bi)

[Iyov 33:23](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Job.33.23.1?vhe=Ibn_Ezra_on_Job_--_Daat&lang=bi)

**Daniel:**

[Daniel 7:14](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Daniel.7.14.6?vhe=Ibn_Ezra_on_Daniel_-_Daat&lang=bi) (also mentioned in [10:21](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Daniel.10.21.1?vhe=Ibn_Ezra_on_Daniel_-_Daat&lang=bi))

**Kohelet:**

[Kohelet 10:18](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Ecclesiastes.10.18.1?vhe=Wikisource&lang=bi)

**Possibly** (not sure if these are to be understood in the same way)**:**

[Beresheet 1:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Genesis.1.5.3?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Beresheet 18:21](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Genesis.18.21.2?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Shemot 15:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Exodus.15.2.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Shemot 16:28](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Exodus.16.28.3?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Devarim 14:22](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Deuteronomy.14.22.2?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Devarim 21:23](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Deuteronomy.21.23.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

[Tehillim 68:24](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Psalms.68.34.2?vhe=Ibn_Ezra_on_Psalms_--_Daat&lang=bi)

[Tehillim 68:36](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Psalms.68.36.1?vhe=Ibn_Ezra_on_Psalms_--_Daat&lang=bi)

[Tehillim 89:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Psalms.89.2.1?vhe=Ibn_Ezra_on_Psalms_--_Daat&lang=bi)